# Was Stark a special kind of Banik / Stykera?

Tags: farscape

In Farscape, Stark is a Stykera, which is a variation of the Banik species. He has the ability to remove his mask and expose the incorporeal part of his being to others, in order to help them cross over into death, or to share thoughts and memories. Stark also has the ability to hide thoughts from interrogators. Other Baniks are mentioned as slaves, but I don't remember any specifics being discussed about the physical differences between Baniks and Stykera.

The only thing I remember being properly discussed was Stark's ability to sense death, in the episode where Scorpius flushed a cargo hanger full of Banik slaves out into space, which was stated as being explicitly due to him being a Stykera.

I can't find any reference as to whether his abilities (or semi-incorporeal form) are an attribute that all Baniks share, or if they are specific to the Stykera, or if it's something more select or unique. Was this ever discussed in the series or the movie?

Comment: I suspect all Banik are mostly energy, like Stark, but some of his abilities (like helping people cross over when they die) are unique to Stykera - but that Stark was a normal Stykera.  I cannot remember any specific dialogue about this, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Farscape Wiki](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Banik):

> Baniks were a Sebaceanoid slave race, with little known information. The race could hide memories from interrogators, even from the Aurora Chair and could also share memories with others by removing a metallic mask covering part of their face to reveal a glowing area of the skull. One variation of the species was the Stykera, who possessed the psychic ability to help others cross over into death. Baniks (Stykera, at least) used their physical bodies only as a link into this reality; their true existence was in the form of energy in another realm.

My read on that is that at least the Stykera, and possibly the Banik themselves, are truly made of the glowing energy we see under Stark's mask, and the fact that he is Stykera gives him the psychic abilities that we see in the show.  So it does not appear that the semi-corporeal nature nor the ability to help "cross over" is unique to Stark.

However, I don't think that is the whole story.  At the end of the PeaceKeeper Wars, Stark has visibly and emotionally changed:

> ...Stark eventually passes it to the other Eidelons and his mental derangement stabilizes. At the end of Farscape: The Peacekeeper Wars Stark removes his metal mask to reveal his "light" gone and his soul at peace.

Which seems to indicate that his mask, emotional condition and probably even the glowing portion of his face is not something natural/native to the race.  There might be an assumption that something occurred during his enslavement to the Peacekeepers, other than just the Aurora Chair, to put him in the state we see in the show.

So my annoying answer would be "Probably sorta".

Answer (score 2):

Based on dialogue from the show, it would seem that all Banik have a certain level of mental fortitude & ability based on this statement from Stark:

> I am of the Banik slave race. Outsiders think that we do not feel. But it's only that our feelings don't always show. Just as this can hide our feelings, we're also able to cloud thoughts from our minds. What I know deep inside, Peacekeepers will never see.

The more advanced abilities, such as the "glowy face" and/or easing someone's pain, seem to be isolated to only Stykeras, which are a rare sub-species of the Banik. The fact that the Stykera are an actual sub-race tells us that the differences are genetic & physiological. In other words, the Stykera are not a religious sect like Zhaan's Pa'u designation - it's not an ability that any old Banik can learn to do.

It's presumed that Stark is referring to the Banik people, not the Stykera people, when he says:

> Peacekeepers killed most of my people. But they kept me alive because
>   I interest them. I'm able to hide thoughts that the chair can't touch.
>   It's almost ironic - what made me a slave now keeps me alive.

The context insinuates that Banik can hide their thoughts from others, but not from the chair device - Stark is therefore apparently much stronger mentally than a normal Banik. The fact that the Scarrans had never encountered the abilities before could indicate that Stark is unique, but it more likely indicates how rare the Stykera are. IMHO, I equate the Stykera sub-race to something like the [Aenar](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Aenar) from Star Trek - a sub-race so rare that even other Andorians viewed them as nearly mythical.

Answer (score 1):

Late in the series, we receive confirmation from Scorpius that his interrogation of Stark was intended to determine the location of the Scarran base, Katratzi.  This squares with Stark's comment in "The Hidden Memory" about Scorpius wanting to know about "a place I went as a boy".  Scorpius likewise reports that Stykera are used in Scarran death rituals.  From this, it follows that while Stykera may be rare, they aren't quite legendary.

Upon obtaining a shipment of Banik slaves in "Liars, Guns, and Money", Scorpius inquires as to whether there are any Stykera among them (presumably to subject any he finds to the Aurora Chair treatment).  From this, we can infer that a.) Stykera are not so rare that his question seems ridiculous, b.) they can be recognized easily by an untrained crew (Scorpius doesn't go on to provide instructions for carrying out any kind of testing procedure to determine if a particular Banik *is* a Stykera), and c.) Stykera aren't rare enough to have been picked out of the shipment prior to this.  (Counter-possibility: having been aware that Stark was involved in the Shadow Depository heist, Scorpius was entertaining the possibility that he might have also infiltrated the Banik slave shipment.)

It's never made entirely clear which of Stark's abilities are Banik-based, which are Stykera-based, and which may be entirely unique to him.  While dialogue pretty strongly implies that not all Baniks are Stykera, it's less clear that all Stykera are necessarily Baniks.  It's at least possible that "Stykera" is something akin to "Jedi," in the sense that it cuts across multiple species (albeit with a very high proportion of Stykera being Banik).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Stykera are a powerful spiritual sect that can sense death, help people cross over into death and absorb all of their memories.
Stark was always referred to as the banik slave and he was a special breed of banik which is why scorpius wanted him as a test subject.

citations [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0029008/bio) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_races_in_Farscape#Banik) is a little less clear but IMDB is how I remember Stark being portrayed.

Comment: Aside from where you've said "he was a special breed of banik", the rest of this answer adds nothing that's not already in the question